# how to set up a virtual server to set up multiple website in xampp locally?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I wanted to try creating multiple stores and storeview. I am following this tutorial 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html 
They have asked me to create a virtual host! how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the Apache folder in XAMPP for Configuration of Vhosts.

File Path :

> f:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

*FYI:* I have installed XAMPP in my F: drive

uncomment the Following lines and edit the vhosts entries as you need

```
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "F:/Projects/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: After uncommenting the base url for my storeviewwill be webmaster@dummy-host.example.com??  or something else

Comment: www.dummy-host.example.com will be your site url and magento folder location is "F:/Projects/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"

Comment: ServerAdmin - what value should it contain